# Netbeans file debugging

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I have netbeans setup with xdebug so it can debug php.  However, this only works if I create a php project.  It will not work if I try opening a stand alone php file.  So my question is, is it possible to debug a stand alone php file which is not part of a netbeans php project?

If that is not possible, how do I debug stand alone php files with netbeans?

Comment: I have a project in Netbeans that is only for ad hoc scripts, for mini apps, for tests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, There is none that I am aware of.

As Myrddin mentioned the debugger needs some configurations that is a part of netbeans project.

but the best way you can debug a single file is to copy it on a project folder, and click the debug project, once the debug session is set then you can browse the PHP File that you want to debug and it will actually go through xdebug.

#### Good Luck!

Comment: Actually you can use CTRL + SHIFT + F5

Answer (score 2):

Each project can have it's own configuration (you can have 1 project that has PHP5.4 interpreter, one the is PHP5.6, one that is a command line and another that is a web project), but if you configure a general PHP 5 Interpreter:
[image: PHP Interpreter]

If you work on a windows machine you can use this code (filename is php.cmd)

```
set XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug"
@php.exe %*
```

If you want to be able to debug, your interpreter should have the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` system variable and make sure it's connected to netbeans. You should set this to the same value in your `Debbugging` section of the PHP's config:
[image: xdebug key]

Next thing - if you right click inside the editor you will have the `Debug File` option, and a prompt window will pop:

[image: Run Arguments]
You don't really need anything here. Just hit the "OK" button.

As you can see, this final result is debug session of the `t1.php` file within `c:\TEMP\` (which is not a working project):

[image: debug session]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: CTRL + SHIFT + F5

You can find the answer here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/run_file_without_project

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it is not possible, because you need some configuration to get the debugging working, and this configuration is part of a project.

You can always use print_r and var_dump to debug a single file. But that is probably not the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

xdebug is very heavy and old tool you can use Kint php debuger here.

its free, so you can [download Here](https://github.com/raveren/kint/)

it's pretty replacement for var_dump(), print_r() and debug_backtrace().

you need to add kint.class.php file using include or require function.

```
require '/kint/Kint.class.php';
```

that's it.

and you can use like

```
########## DUMP VARIABLE ###########################
Kint::dump($GLOBALS, $_SERVER); // pass any number of parameters
// or simply use d() as a shorthand:
d($_SERVER);
########## DEBUG BACKTRACE #########################
Kint::trace();

more help is available on https://github.com/raveren/kint/

Good Luck :)
```

Comment: The question was how to enable debugging within netbeans, not which classes for debugging exists. Kint is no replacement for xdebug. You cannot pause the process while running, check current state and variables, do a step-by-step debugging and so on.

Comment: @Dekel Did you checked full Documentations of Kint? if not then see here [link] http://raveren.github.io/kint/

Comment: I indeed checked the full documentation, and also checked the code. Will appreciate if you can direct me to the place where explains how to add a breakpoint within my IDE (netbeans, to be related to the question here) and real DEBUG the file I'm working on. How exactly to move line-by-line, step-by-step to have a real debugging process. Don't get me wrong - Kint is a great solution. But it's not a PHP debugger, and no replacement for xdebug.